# Inequality in a Dirichlet BVP

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For the Drichlet boundary value problem 
 $Lu = -u''+p(x)u'+q(x)u = f(x), \; \; \; x \in I=[a,b]$. with $u(a)=u(b)=0$. Then for $v \in H^2(I) \cap H_0^1(I)$ show that $\left\lvert \right\rvert v \left\lvert \right\rvert_{H^2(I)} \leq C_0 \left\lvert \right\rvert Lv \left\lvert \right\rvert_{L^2(I)}$. $p, q \in C^{\infty}$.

I am reading a paper for my research on finite element methods and I came across this inequality. I don't seem to fathom how to prove this. Help please?

Comment: I suppose there are further assumptions on $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @Siminore  $p , q$ are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: It is clearly a very special case of the standard elliptic regularity theory for PDEs: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator#Elliptic_regularity_theorem.  I cannot devise an ad hoc proof right now.

Comment: How do you know you don't have a non-trivial solution $v$ of $Lv=0$? If you do have such a solution, then your inequality is not going to hold. For example, if $Lu=-u''-u$ on $[0,\pi]$, then $L\sin(x)=0$ and $\sin(0)=\sin(\pi)=0$; but, you do not get $\|\sin\|_{H^{2}} \le C_0\|L\sin \|_{L^{2}}=0$ for any $C_0 \ge 0$.